# Tabular view for enumeration on TwinCAT3

Tags: twincat, codesys, visual-studio-shell

There is a visual problem as I declare an enumeration on TwinCAT3 as has been shown in the following:
[image]

here is my simple declaration;

```
VAR
state:(init , operate, stop);//a simple example of enum declaration 
END_VAR
```

and here is the code that I faced before crashing:

[image]

Current XAE version: 3.14024.47

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you try to change the enum names, lets say state_[name]? It could be some error due to reserved global names, I use local enums all the time, no problems, same version of TC.

Comment: Oh, I was too quick and didnt notice the gif problem when you clicked the button... That is definetly a TC issue, you should report it to Beckhoff if it happes with multiple versions.

Comment: This is a hard crash, you should report it to the vendor (Beckhoff in this case)

Comment: PS. I replicated the same issue on Schneider Electric Machine Expert 2.0.2.1, so it's probably a bug in the CODESYS core